# Fusioncharts custom color based on object attribute

Tags: jquery, fusioncharts

I'm trying to hack into the FusionCharts object to control color of each data element independently of the basic "paletteColors" object.

I need to modify it so that, for example all items with label "New" get the same color (red for example). And all items with the label "Complete" get a specific color (gray for example).

So, I can have multiple charts, each with different data (one chart may have "New" and "Complete" data labels and another chart may have "Funding" and "Errors" label) but the color values will be distinct for each data point across multiple charts.

```
$.each(jsonDataPoints, function (index, obj) {
            var hoverText = obj.label + " (" + obj.value + ")";
            obj.toolText = hoverText; //This sets the text to display when a pie chart is hovered.
            obj.displayValue = hoverText; //This sets the chart labels.

                if (obj.label = "New") { 
                    obj.color = "#ff0000";
                }
                else if(obj.label = "Complete") { 
                    obj.color = "#cccccc"; 
                }
                else if(obj.label = "Funding") { 
                    obj.color = "#888888"; 
                }

                else{
                    obj.color = "#000000";
                }
        });


var pieChart = new FusionCharts({
            type: 'pie2D',
            renderAt: containerId,
            registerWithJS: '1',
            dataFormat: 'json',
            dataSource: {
                "chart": {
                    "enableRotation": "0",
                    "animation": "1",
                    "showToolTip": "1",
                    "showPercentInTooltip": "0",
                    "showBorder": "0",
                    "showLegend": "0",
                    "decimals": "1",
                    "formatNumber": "1",
                    "formatNumberScale": "0",
                    "inthousandSeparator": ",",
                    "indecimalSeparator": ".",
                    "enableSmartLabels": "1",
                    "height": "100%",
                    "width": "100%",
                    "bgColor": "#FFFFFF",
                    //"paletteColors": "E58403,60CA9E,8F5097,569C3F,2D6CA2,5B6770,8F6A2A,5F407A,872B4B,572C5F,244C5A",
                    "chartBottomMargin": "5",
                    "chartTopMargin": "5",
                    "showPlotBorder": "1",
                    "plotBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
                    "plotBorderThickness": "1",
                    "startingAngle": "90"
                },
                "data": jsonDataPoints
            }
        });
        pieChart.render();
```

In other words, I don't want "Funding" to have the same chart color as "New". I want "Funding" to always be the same color no matter which chart it appears in (I have a dashboard with 3-4 charts)

Am I on the right track with the code below? Obviously I'm missing something because it's not working (all values are red, which is the same as the "New" label. New should be red but each subsequent data point should have its own unique color as specified in my if/else code branch below)

Comment: Can you share a fiddle link of your implementation?

Comment: Sorry I can't. It's a standard Fusion Charts script. I'm just trying to customize the color beyond the API allows through paletteColors array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify a comma separated list of colors for use in different data series. The colors are selected from the list in a round-robin way for each data series.

```
{
   "chart": {
      "palettecolors": "5d62b5,29c3be,f2726f"
   }
}
```

To know more about this please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/data-plot#color-different-data-plots

Refer demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/c24e59hm/3/